# How to execute arbitrary pipes in c and continue

Tags: c, exec, fork, pipe, gnu

I'm trying to fork and then execute two or more piped commands in the child process. My idea is to use a while loop to continuously fork and execute the command in one process while continuing the loop in the other. Here's my code:

```
void
execute_pipe_command(command_t *c)
{
    command_t command = *c;
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid > 0) {
        int status;
        while(waitpid(pid, &status, 0) < 0)
            continue;
        if(!WIFEXITED(status))
            error(1, errno, "Child exit error");
        command->status = WEXITSTATUS(status);
        return;
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        while(command->type == PIPE_COMMAND)
        {
            int fd[2]; pipe(fd);
            pid = fork();
            if(pid > 0) {
                close(fd[0]);
                dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
                char **args = command->u.command[1]->u.word;
                execvp(args[0], args);
            } else if (pid == 0) {
                close(fd[1]);
                dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
                command = command->u.command[0];
                continue;
            } else {
                error(1, errno, "forking error");
            }
        }
        char **args = command->u.word;
        execvp(args[0], args);
    } else {
        error(1, errno, "forking error");
    }
}
```

Command is a struct that hold it's type, and if it's a pipe command it holds left and right children commands. Otherwise if it's a simple command it holds an array of strings that make up the command.

When I call this function with a pipe command like `ls | cat` it should execute the commands, but instead it behaves weirdly. The first two piped commands will run but won't give control back to the program. Instead it'll hang. The subsequent commands are just ignored. So if I give this `ls | cat | wc` this function will print ls and won't exit until I give a SIGINT.

I'm pretty much confused as to what's going on. I'd appreciate if someone could point out the problem.

Comment: Isn't the lat if reversed? I guess the parent should move to the next command and the child do the exec... right?

Answer (score 0):

`while (command->type == PIPE_COMMAND)` is always true! This is way it hangs.